# How can I calculate two points along the normal of a path given only two points from that path?

Tags: java, math, coordinates

Sorry about the title, It's really not a good one.

So I have created a path of points for my game. This path is "randomly" generated so I never know what it's going to look like all I know is it will never cross itself.

What I am trying to do is take any point along that path and calculate 2 points exactly 10 units away from the line in the direction of the normal vectors on either side. An example would be I have the points of the lane markers in the center of a two lane road. I want to calculate the location of both curbs for any given point on the lane markers.

I've attempted to just calculate the normal slope which I think I'm getting the correct result for that, but I don't know how I can say "a point 10 units away on this line".

If you need some extra info I can gladly provide it.

Someone asked for code:

```
//These are set elsewhere
float x1;
float y1;
float x2;
float y2;
float Distance = 10;
```

Basically, this is what I want to do, but in code:

```
((x1+x2)/2, (y1+y2)/2) +- Distance * (-(y2-y1), (x2-x1)) / sqrt((x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2)
```

Comment: It looks like your question is more about maths than about programming.

Comment: To an extent. However if I ask on mathoverflow I will get formulas and equations that when trying to convert to code makes no sense. I can do it on paper, I can't translate it to code. Posting here will help me get a more code specific answer.

Comment: Well, we'll need code to be able to give you an answer in code.  Right now we got nothing.  (Some math books would help you out if you are doing this sort of work.  I think *Graphic Gems I* has various algorithms for parameterizing line segments.)

Comment: Added some code.

Comment: Your pseudocode is right. What's wrong with its implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't take credit for this because I found it somewhere else, but this is the implementation of the equation I was attempting to solve. I'm going to post in case others stumble across this in the future.

Please note: this is horribly optimized and the variable names are a bit inaccurate (particularly left/right), but it was a proof of concept that I will be implementing into a larger project.

```
            //Calculate left
            float left_x1 = current.x;
            float left_y1 = current.y;
            float left_x2 = previous.x;
            float left_y2 = previous.y;
            float D = 30;

            float left_dx = left_x1-left_x2;
            float left_dy = left_y1-left_y2;
            float left_dist = (float) Math.sqrt(left_dx*left_dx + left_dy*left_dy);
            left_dx /= left_dist;
            left_dy /= left_dist;
            float left_x3 = left_x1 + D * left_dy;
            float left_y3 = left_y1 - D * left_dx;
            float left_x4 = left_x1 - D * left_dy;
            float left_y4 = left_y1 + D * left_dx;

            //Calculate right
            float right_x1 = previous.x;
            float right_y1 = previous.y;
            float right_x2 = old.x;
            float right_y2 = old.y;

            float right_dx = right_x1-right_x2;
            float right_dy = right_y1-right_y2;
            float dist = (float) Math.sqrt(right_dx*right_dx + right_dy*right_dy);
            right_dx /= dist;
            right_dy /= dist;
            float right_x3 = right_x1 + D * right_dy;
            float right_y3 = right_y1 - D * right_dx;
            float right_x4 = right_x1 - D * right_dy;
            float right_y4 = right_y1 + D * right_dx;

            //Draw bounds
            shapeRenderer.line(right_x3, right_y3, left_x3, left_y3);
            shapeRenderer.line(right_x4, right_y4, left_x4, left_y4);
```